# How to label multiple points in animation with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, animation

How to provide multiple annotations for different points on a particular frame in an animation. For example, I am plotting five points on a map and I need to annotate them as A, B, C, D, and E.

```
import mpl_toolkits
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np

map = Basemap(projection='robin', resolution = 'l', area_thresh = 1000.0,
          lat_0=0, lon_0=-130)
x,y = map(0,0)
point = map.plot(x, y, 'ro', markersize=4)[0]

def init():
    point.set_data([], [])
    return point,

def animate(i):
    lon = np.random.random_integers(-130,130, 5)
    lat = np.random.random_integers(-130,130, 5)
    x, y = map(lon, lat)
    point.set_data(x, y)
    annotations = np.array('A','B','C','D','E')
    return point, annotations

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, init_func= init, frames= 100,interval= 500, blit=True)
```

Comment: You have to create as many `annotation` object as you need. One annotation can only have one coordinate. I could help more if you were to provide a [*Minimal*, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (emphasis on minimal)

Comment: I have tried to address the issue by writing simpler code. How to return multiple annotation objects in this case.

Comment: Annotations are created with `annotate()`. See https://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plotting_data.html#annotate and https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/annotations.html